# Transfer Photoshop animation timeline screenshots into After Effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could best transfer a Photoshop video timeline with screen shots to After Effects?

I was creating a gif then it became a huge production of 301 screenshots and over 600 layers. I really love the video and I know it will be easier to finish it in After Effects.

The only thing I can think to do is to convert layers that create individual moving objects into video files as separate Photoshop projects then transfer them individually into After Effects. This is a difficult process so if anyone by chance has any better ideas to smoothly transition this Photoshop video into After Effects it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what the state of your project is at the moment, but if you have an actual animation that will play on your Photoshop timeline, you can render it as an image sequence (which you can import into Ae directly), or as uncompressed .avi.

If that doesn't give you what you need, amplify the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm over eight years late to this party, but in case someone else has the same question, number your files 1 through 301 and import them as a series into After Effects by choosing File>Import and selecting the the first file, import as "footage," and import as a sequence. You only have to choose the first file, but AE will pull in all of them as a stack that you can drop on the timeline. In the bottom right of the Projects panel, click the button to Interpret Footage and use the pop up to set the frame rate. Drop the stack on the timeline and you're in business.